# Finding how 3 hunter can share their prey

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Three hunters hit the moving target with probabilities $0,6, 0,4$ and $0,2$. When they saw a deer they shot in one time. After it they saw that only one bullet reached the target. So how they can shere a prey?

I think first I need to find $\mathbb{P}(X)$ where $X$ is event that deer was shot. $\mathbb{P}(X)=\mathbb{P}(  (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cup  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C)) $ am I right? When I will find it I will make a proportion and will find how they can share a prey.

So if I am right, I have problem. I think I am doing something wrong.
$\mathbb{P}(X)=\mathbb{P}(  (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cup  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C))=
\mathbb{P}( (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C})) +\mathbb{P} (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C) - \mathbb{P}(  (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cap  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C))=  
\mathbb{P}(A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) + \mathbb{P}((\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cap  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C))-\mathbb{P}(  (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \cap (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cap  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C))+\mathbb{P} (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C) - 
\mathbb{P} (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) - \mathbb{P}( (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cap  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C))+ \mathbb{P}(  (A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \cap (\overline{A}\cap B \cap \overline{C}) \cap  (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}  \cap C))= ?$ Where is my mistake and how I can continue it? Maybe there is easier way?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ should be the event the deer was shot exactly once, because that is the information you have.  You are trying to assess $P(A|X)$, the chance that $A$ hit the deer given that exactly one person hit the deer, and the same for the other two.  The probability that $A$ hit and the others did not is $0.6\cdot (1-0.4) \cdot (1-0.2)=0.288$.  Compute the corresponding probability for the other two and scale up to make the sum be $1$.

Comment: So $\mathbb{P}(A|X)=0.288$ $\mathbb{P}(B|X)=0.192$ $\mathbb{P}(C|X)=0.048$ than $0.288+0.192+0.048=0,528$ Whats next? For first hunter it will be $ 0.288/0.528=0.(54)$ for second $0.192/0.528=0.(36)$ and for third hunter $0.048/0.528=0.(09)$ right?

Comment: Your result is correct but your notation is wrong.  Based on your calculation $P(A|X)=\frac {54}{99}$ which is what you mean by $0.(54)$